# Validation not applied to request scoped beans

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, cdi

Platform: JBoss AS 7.

I am seeing a strange behavior with JSR 303 bean validation and a request scoped CDI managed bean. System never seems to apply the validation rules and always passes validation.

Below is a code snippet.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
class Person {
    @Size(min=3, max=25, message="Please enter a valid name")
    private String firstName;
    //Getters and setters...
}

@WebServlet("/ValidationTest")
public class ValidationTest extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    Person p1;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        p1.setFirstName("A");
        validate(p1);

        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.setFirstName("B");
        validate(p2);
    }

    public void validate(Object o) {
        ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = null;
        validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        ValidatorContext validatorContext = validatorFactory.usingContext();
        javax.validation.Validator beanValidator = validatorContext
                .getValidator();

        Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = beanValidator.validate(o);

        System.out.println("Object is valid: " + violations.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

The output from this is:

```
Object is valid: true
Object is valid: false
```

The injected bean p1 is deemed to be valid, which should not happen. Validation of p2 fails which is expected. If I make the Person bean dependent scoped then p1 is correctly deemed to be invalid. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have duplicated the behavior in TomEE. So, I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I haven't done this exactly, but I think you can inject the Validator that the server starts for you.

Comment: Injecting the validtor will reduce the amount of code, but, the final outcome remains the same. I think the problem is that CDI is not compatible with JSR 303.

Comment: CDI Spec section 3.6 says both the ValidatorFactory and the Validator can be injected and are available after the application starts. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the scope. Try making it dependent and see what happens, or try a different scope.